# M-ary simulation in labview

Tags: labview

I am totally new to LabVIEW .I am having the block diagram of M-ary communication system:

[image: Block diagram]

[image: Front panel]

How can I create the same project by myself?

Where can i find these components?.A step by step approach is welcomed.

I am getting an error in the above simulation
**You have two or more cluster data types wired together, but the clusters have different kinds or numbers of elements.
Cluster FSK system parameters, a cluster of 3 elements,
conflicts with cluster ASK system parameters, a cluster of 2 elements.**

please help

Answer (score 0):

In your example the broken wire (black dashed wire with the red cross) is caused by connecting two different (incompatible) data types. The vi to the left is passing out the datatype [image: FSK system parameters] and the two to the right expect [image: ASK System Parameters].

I think what has happened here is the RF tookit allows you to use both FSK and ASK as modulation types and the wrong one has been selected. The left vi has a polymorphic selector under the icon which can be used to select different operations. If you can change this from FSK(M) to ASK(M) then this should remove the broken wire.

There is an example on the NI website that my be of use to you. This includes steps to create a working vi: [RF Simulation Demo: Amplitude Shift Keying](http://www.ni.com/example/30106/en/)